# Adobe Animate CC - Responsive not working on mobile

Tags: responsive, adobe-animate

I've got a situation where after selecting the make responsive and both settings in the publish settings so I have;

```
makeResponsive(true,'both',false,1);
```

In my script.

The animation scales with the browser window and even in Responsive design mode in safari. But if you actually view it on a phone (in this case an iPhone7) it doesn't resize properly.

The url is;

http://energy.fullfatwebsitedesign.co.uk

And the iPhone view looks like this;

[iPhone Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1IOl.png)

Is there another setting I need to make?

Answer (score 0):

After testing I had;

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

in the head. By adding initial-scale=1

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

if you canvas below 1000px will this problem occurs. Because mobile with is there screen resolution, not is device width. so need to add below meta. set width = device-width and set cannot scalable. if not to add below meta. iphone screen width will be 1100px. you can try using javascript to alert window.innerWidth. `<script>alert(window.innerWidth)</script>`. you can to see the width is 1100px, but added below meta. width will change to 375px on iphoneX

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" >
```

Comment: Could you please edit your answer not just with Google Translate or similar tool, so it'll be clear